# Array in the function does not display correctly

Tags: c, arrays, function

The program is used to display the winning team which score the highest score within 3 teams in a 3x4 array.

There is something wrong in the `input` or `teamscore` function. I can't find the errors and my input in the `input` function can't be stored and calculated  in `teamscore` funtion.

```
void input(int a[NROW][NCOL])
{
    int x,y;
    double team;

        for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter your team: ");
            scanf("%i",&team);

            for(y=0;y<NCOL;y++)
            {
                printf("\nEnter the score: ");
                scanf("%lf",&a[x][y]);
            }

        }
}
```

```
int teamscore(int a[NROW][NCOL])
{
    int x,y,highest,team;
    double sum;

        for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<NCOL;y++)
            {
                sum = sum + a[x][y];
            }
        }

        for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
                for(y=0;y<NCOL;y++)
                        if (a[x][y]>highest)
                        {
                            highest=a[x][y];
                        }

        return highest;
}
```

All of my output is 0.

This is my entire code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NROW 3
#define NCOL 4

void initialize(int a[NROW][NCOL])
{
    int x,y;
        for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<NCOL;y++)
            {
                a[x][y]=0;
            }
        }

}

/* Display array in a matrix form*/
void disp_arr(int a[NROW][NCOL])
{
    int x,y;
        for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<NCOL;y++)
            {
                printf("%i ",a[x][y]);
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* Input the invidual score for 3 team*/
void input(int a[NROW][NCOL])
{
    int x,y;
    double team;

        for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter your team: ");
            scanf("%i",&team);

            for(y=0;y<NCOL;y++)
            {
                printf("\nEnter the score: ");
                scanf("%lf",&a[x][y]);
            }

        }
}

/* Calculate the total of score for each team and return the index for the 
row with the highest team score */
int teamscore(int a[NROW][NCOL])
{
    int x,y,highest,team;
    double sum;

        for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<NCOL;y++)
            {
                sum = sum + a[x][y];
            }
        }

        for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
                for(y=0;y<NCOL;y++)
                        if (a[x][y]>highest)
                        {
                            highest=a[x][y];
                        }

        return highest;
}

int main()
{
    int ar[NROW][NCOL];
    int team;
    initialize(ar);

    disp_arr(ar);

    input(ar);

    disp_arr(ar);

    team=teamscore(ar);


    printf("\nThe winniing team is Team %i",&team);

    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate for some helps.

Thanks!

Comment: In `teamscore`, you do not initialize `sum` to zero, but you should.  Similarly, you don't initialize `highest`, though that can't necessarily be set to zero safely; you usually set it to the first (or last) value in the array and compare other values against that.  Also, don't forget to include a newline at the end of lines of output.

Comment: Also, in `input()`, you have: `double team;

    for (x = 0; x < NROW; x++)
    {   
        printf("\nEnter your team: ");
        scanf("%i", &team);` — but that's a type mismatch.  Your compiler should be complaining.  If it isn't, either turn up the warning levels or get a better compiler.  Do not pass `&i` to `printf()`.  It's not clear why you calculate `sum` since you never use it.

Comment: And you're using the wrong format in `scanf("%lf", &a[x][y]);` — `a` is an array of `int`, not `double`.

Comment: when you read from the keyboard: do a function that uses fgets instead, then convert the result to type you need. it is much easier and safer to handle than scanf's funny formatting and buffer. e.g. `int getInt(int defaultValue) 
{ 
  char ar[32]; 
  if (fgets(ar,sizeof(ar),stdin)!=NULL)
  {
    return atoi(ar);
  }
  else
  {
    return defaultValue;
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for pinpoint the mistakes that i made

Comment: Tanks @AndersK.for your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is ambiguous as to what you intend the `team` to be. You prompt for user input and then attempt to store `team` as `double`? Unless you expect your team number to be, e.g. `123.456`, just make your team an `int`, e.g. team `1`, team `10`, etc..

The next problem you have is taking input for a team number, but providing no manner for that entry to be usable in any other function other than `input`. If you don't pass another parameter to capture the user input for `team`, then your teams are just the indexes for `a` and it is unnecessary to prompt for that input. To make the user input available back in `main`, just pass another parameter (or just add +1 to `NCOL` and use col `0` for the team number). The following is a way to capture the user input for the team number (e.g. team `125, 190, ...`) and make that available back in the caller:

```
int main (void) {

    int hi_index = 0,
        teams[NROW] = {0},      /* note array of NROW for teams */
        ar[NROW][NCOL] = {{0}};
    ...
    input (ar, teams);
```

then you can make `input` capture that information by passing the `teams` array as a parameter, e.g.

```
/* Input the individual score for 3 team*/
void input (int a[NROW][NCOL], int teams[NROW])
```

You must ***validate*** all user input. When working with `scanf` that means validating the **return** -- that the number of conversions (as specified in the *format string*) did in fact take place. You must also check whether the user generated a manual `EOF` (<kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze). If the user cancels input, your code should gracefully handle that condition. If the user just provided *invalid input* and the conversion failed due to a *matching* or *input* failure, you need to determine if you will inform the user and prompt the user to "*Try Again*" or whether you will treat it as a cancellation.

To approach user input in this manner, one method is just to loop until you receive valid input or the user cancels, e.g. in your `input` function, you could do the following:

```
        for (;;) {      /* loop until valid input or user canceled */
            int rtn;

            printf ("\nEnter your team: ");
            rtn = scanf ("%d", &teams[x]);

            if (rtn == 1)
                break;
            else if (rtn == EOF) {
                fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            /* (you should empty stdin here) */
            empty_stdin();
        }
```

**note:** to empty `stdin`, you can simply read with `getchar()` until `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered, e.g.

```
/* function to empty stdin */
void empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

Your `printf` and `scanf` *format specifier* mismatches are already covered in the comments.

Putting all those pieces together, and presuming you actually want whole numbers as the team numbers instead of weird team numbers like `123.456`, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for exit, EXIT_FAILURE */

#define NROW 3
#define NCOL 4

/* Display array in a matrix form*/
void disp_arr (int a[NROW][NCOL], int teams[NROW])
{
    int x, y;

    putchar ('\n');
    for ( x = 0; x < NROW; x++)
    {
        printf ("team %3d : ", teams[x]);
        for (y = 0; y < NCOL; y++)
            printf (" %4d", a[x][y]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

/* function to empty stdin */
void empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

/* Input the individual score for 3 team*/
void input (int a[NROW][NCOL], int teams[NROW])
{
    int x, y;

    for (x = 0; x < NROW; x++)
    {
        for (;;) {      /* loop until valid input or user canceled */
            int rtn;

            printf ("\nEnter your team: ");
            rtn = scanf ("%d", &teams[x]);

            if (rtn == 1)
                break;
            else if (rtn == EOF) {
                fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            empty_stdin();
        }
        for (y = 0; y < NCOL; y++)
        {
            for (;;) {  /* same loop until valid or canceled */
                int rtn;

                printf ("Enter team[%d] score[%d]: ", teams[x], y + 1);
                rtn = scanf ("%d", &a[x][y]);

                if (rtn == 1)
                    break;
                else if (rtn == EOF) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n");
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
                empty_stdin();
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Calculate the total of score for each team.
* return the index for the row with the highest team score 
*/
int teamscore (int a[NROW][NCOL])
{
    int x, y, 
        highest = 0,
        hi_index = 0, 
        sum[NROW] = {0};

    for (x = 0; x < NROW; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < NCOL; y++)
            sum[x] += a[x][y];
        if (sum[x] > highest) {
            highest = sum[x];
            hi_index = x;
        }
    }

    return hi_index;
}

int main (void) {

    int hi_index = 0,
        teams[NROW] = {0},
        ar[NROW][NCOL] = {{0}};

    // initialize (ar); /* ar is not a VLA, initialize at declaration */

    disp_arr (ar, teams);

    input (ar, teams);

    disp_arr (ar, teams);

    hi_index = teamscore (ar);

    printf ("\nThe winning team is Team %d\n", teams[hi_index]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/team

team   0 :     0    0    0    0
team   0 :     0    0    0    0
team   0 :     0    0    0    0

Enter your team: 123
Enter team[123] score[1]: 10
Enter team[123] score[2]: 12
Enter team[123] score[3]: 14
Enter team[123] score[4]: 16

Enter your team: 138
Enter team[138] score[1]: 12
Enter team[138] score[2]: 14
Enter team[138] score[3]: 16
Enter team[138] score[4]: 18

Enter your team: 187
Enter team[187] score[1]: 11
Enter team[187] score[2]: 13
Enter team[187] score[3]: 15
Enter team[187] score[4]: 17

team 123 :    10   12   14   16
team 138 :    12   14   16   18
team 187 :    11   13   15   17

The winning team is Team 138
```

**Example of Invalid & Canceled Input**

```
$ ./bin/team

team   0 :     0    0    0    0
team   0 :     0    0    0    0
team   0 :     0    0    0    0

Enter your team: The Mighty Ducks
error: invalid input.

Enter your team: user canceled input.
```

Look things over and let me know if I made any error in my presumptions about the type for your teams etc. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The type for my team should be integer so your presumptions are correct. Well explained and i need to take some times to understand it. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

1. use %d for integer instead of %lf. %lf for double
   void input(int a[NROW][NCOL])
   {
   int x,y;
   double team;

   ```
   for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
   {
       printf("\nEnter your team: ");
       scanf("%i",&team);

       for(y=0;y<NCOL;y++)
       {
           printf("\nEnter the score: ");
           scanf("%d",&a[x][y]);// use %d for integer instead of %lf. %lf for double
       }

   }
   ```

   }
2. Lots of mistake in teamscore function. Sample code:

   ```
   int teamscore(int a[NROW][NCOL])
   {
   int x,y,highest,team;
   double sum;

   for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
   {
       sum =0;
       for(y=0;y<NCOL;y++)
       {
           sum = sum + a[x][y];
       }
       a[x][0] = sum;
   }
   highest = a[0][0];
   team = 0;

   for(x=0;x<NROW;x++)
       if (a[x][0]>highest)
       {
           highest = a[x][0];
           team=x;
       }
   return team;// return row number
   ```

   }
3. use team variable only instead of `&team` in main while printing. &team = Address of the team variable.

   ```
   printf("\nThe winniing team is Team %d",team);
   ```

Comment: You may want to discuss what `team` is and how it is not "*the index for the row with the highest team score*".

Comment: Now i know i have done a lot of mistakes.Thanks for the assists and the final output is incorrect.